# Verifying IPv6 implementation

Tags: embedded, ipv6, verification

My development team is looking to implement IPv6 on embedded platform. One the primary issues we're encountering at this stage is creating our test environment. Currently the only verification suite that we have found is the one created by TAHI.org. Running through an initial setup of this suite, it appears to only be for *NIX based implementations.

Is there an available solution for creating a test environment other than this or going to UNH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TAHI tests, while they require a FreeBSD box to run, do not require that the target be UNIX based. In fact, we ran them against a VxWorks-based embedded device.

If memory serves, there are several "remote" scripts that you must implement,  however, to (for example) reboot your target device so that compliance can be tested in cases where the IPv6 interface must go down and come back up.

UNH uses essentially the same tests as the TAHI suite. Running the TAHI tests is therefore highly recommended.